# How to tell what file a packet came from after files merged

Tags: pcap, tshark, editcap

I am dealing with a large number of pcap files from numerous collection sources. I need to programmatically filter and I am using tshark for that, so I am merging all the files together first using mergecap.  The problem with that is I also need collection point information which is only available in the capture file name. I tried using editpcap to add in per-packet comments specifying original file however that is untenable (see below for explanation).  Any ideas how to track the original file after pcap files merged?

**why editcap solution won't work**
I considered using editcap to add per-packet comments on every packet before merging ([How to add a comment to all packets in numerous pcap files before merging into a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62476954/how-to-add-a-comment-to-all-packets-in-numerous-pcap-files-before-merging-into-a/62477362?noredirect=1#comment110512656_62477362)) however the problem with this approach is that editcap requires every packet comment to be individually specified on the command line (you can't specify a range of packets). Thats hundreds of thousands of comments and the command line won't support that.  Additionally, if I try to run editpcap with just a few comments at a time over and over it rewrites the entire file every time, leading to thousands of file rewrites. Also not viable.

Answer (score 2):

If your original capture files are in .pcapng format, then each one contains an Interface Description Block or IDB.  When you run [`mergecap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/mergecap.html) to merge them, you can specify that IDB's not be merged using the `-I none` option.  In this way, the interface number will be unique per original file and you can add a column that shows that information to easily differentiate the source of each packet by interface ID, or you can apply a display filter to isolate only those packets from a particular capture file.

The filter or column to use would be the **frame.interface_id** field, but you could also filter by **frame.interface_name** or **frame.interface_description** if those field values all have different values too, but there's no guarantee those fields will be unique as the interface name and/or description might contain the same information, even if the capture files originate from different machines.

Comment: unfortunately, the capture files are pcap not pcapng and as you said I can't rely on the IDB being unique due to 'business logic'. However, this does make me wonder if post-collection I could iterate through all pcap files, add an IDB description and save as a new pcapng, and then merge all pcapng's together. Can IDB descriptions be added after collection similiar to IDB comments? And can it be done programatically?

Comment: Currently when you convert pcap files to pcapng using `editcap`, a dummy Ethernet IDB is added. ('Editcap` is a command-line tool, so conversion can be scripted.)  Unfortunately, all pcapng files created this way won't contain an interface_description and only "unknown" as the interface_name; however, `mergecap` will enumerate all interfaces and so each packet will at least indicate the enumerated interface ID from which it came in the interface_id field, so you should be able to use this information to know which packet came from which original file and capture point.